# are there any alternatives to developing android apps other than with eclipse

Tags: java, android, mobile, ide, eclipse

Ever since I installed the android sdk and avd manager in eclipse for java developers, it's been pretty simple to create apps for the mobile device. The only issue I have is eclipse is way too slow for comfort. Sometimes it takes up to a minute to do simple things like opening up a java class file.

Are there any faster ways to utilize the android sdk/avd manager plugins in some alternative IDE that is stable?

Comment: That sounds ridiculously unusual. I've been using eclipse for android apps for over a year now and on four different computers and I have never had such problems. The longest wait is opening eclipse at first which takes 10-15 seconds. Class files open right away with a double click. It sounds like there may be a problem with your computer or maybe your installation of eclipse.

Comment: This page details installation and would be a good place to start looking for info on using the SDK without eclipse: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: Your last sentence is just flamebait. There are people who program using a “command prompt”. Actually I do all my game programming from a bash or zsh command prompt.

Comment: Well there is an alternative, which is where you write the JVM bytecode instructions, in a hex editor, but I don't think that would appeal to most developers.

Comment: I think it the difference between 32 and 64 bit architecture because when i installed eclipse on my 64 bit laptop it ran significantly faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have a problem with your eclipse setup and perhaps being more specific on the error would help. For instance, there is a known bug with Eclipse Helios [autocomplete being very slow with the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953012/eclipse-android-sdk-slow-content-assist-performance). Do you have the latest dev tools and eclipse plugin?

To answer the question, Netbrains' IntelliJ IDEA has [android support](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/android/) and there is a [plugin for NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans) that allows android development also. For C++ code this can even be done in Visual Studio (see most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development)) as well as C# in Visual Studio with [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

I will choose to ignore your comment on notepad and the command prompt and for the sake of completeness list some other tools:

You do not need to use a graphical tool at all in order to develop an Android project. Google provides help for [Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) which requires use of adb and Apache Ant. Software can be developed using any IDE or text editor. Personally I use Vim, but Emacs has an [Android development minor mode](http://gitorious.org/emacs-android-minor-mode) that provides nice key bindings for working with the Android SDK.

For additional information see the StackOverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929574/what-are-alternatives-to-eclipse-for-developing-android-applications) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387382/is-there-an-alternative-ide-to-develop-android-applications-other-then-eclipse).

Comment: that sounds good i probably would prefer NetBeans over eclipse anyway, it is just because the android plug in for eclipse is very useful. But i will give that a try thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse shouldn't be that slow, you may have some thing wrong. Anyways to answer you question there is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html). I use it for web development and find that it is better at project management than Eclipse one you get used to it.

JetBrains has things such as auto complete down to a science compared to either Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Comment: "JetBrains has things such as auto complete down to a science compared to either Eclipse or Visual Studio."
Well it has defo not. Have been using Intellij about a year now because of its better Scala plugin, and everything, from autocompletion, to navigation to project management, is inferior to Eclipse. It's not bad but can't see anything about it thats "down to a science". It would have been 15 years ago, now, it's just what you would except..